# Conditional SQLite check constraint text error

Tags: android, image, sqlite, constraints

I have this code in SQLite:

```
create table Avisos ( 
idAviso int primary key, 
Tipo text  not null CHECK (Tipo = "Semaforos" or Tipo = "Senalizacion" or Tipo = "Calzada"  Tipo = "Parquimetro" Tipo = "Otro"), 
Descripcion text not null, 
Estado text not null check (Estado = "En proceso" or Estado = "Resuelta"), 
Ubicacion text not null, 
Foto blob not null, 
idUsuario int not null, 
Fecha date not null, 
FOREIGN KEY (idUsuario) REFERENCES Usuarios(idUsuario))
```

I have an error in the constraint Check (Tipo = "Semaforos" and .....)

I've searching and I found that if I want to add an image in SQLite, I have to define the image with "blob", someone knows if it's well?

Comment: Try replacing `"` with the proper SQL string delimiter: `'`

Answer (score 0):

This makes the problem very hard to see:

```
Tipo text not null CHECK (Tipo = "Semaforos" or Tipo = "Senalizacion" or Tipo = "Calzada"  Tipo = "Parquimetro" Tipo = "Otro"),
```

You should format your code better, then it's easier to see what is missing:

```
Tipo text not null CHECK (Tipo = "Semaforos"    or
                          Tipo = "Senalizacion" or
                          Tipo = "Calzada"          -- here
                          Tipo = "Parquimetro"      -- and here
                          Tipo = "Otro"),
```

Anyway, a check for multiple values can be made simpler with IN:

```
CHECK (Tipo IN ('Semaforos', 'Senalizacion', 'Calzada', 'Parquimetro', 'Otro'))
```